# Combine Lens into a Lens of a tuple

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

Given

```
data Person = Person { _name :: String }
makeClassy ''Person
```

which creates a

```
name :: Lens' Person String
```

I can define the following lens which uses `name` inside a tuple.

```
sndPerson :: Lens' (a, Person) (a, String)
sndPerson = lens
    (\(a, p) -> (a, p ^. name)) 
    (\(_, p) (a, n) -> (a, p & name .~ n))
```

Is there a nicer/canonical way to define `sndPerson` above?

Comment: What about `_2 . name`?

Comment: That gives the type `forall s t b (f :: * -> *).
              (Field2 s t b b, HasPerson b, Functor f) =>
              (String -> f String) -> s -> f t` which is not `Lens' (a, Person) (a, String)`

Comment: That is, the type`Lens' (a, Person) String`, not `Lens' (a, Person) (a, String)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`alongside`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.4/docs/Control-Lens-Lens.html#v:alongside) turns a pair of lenses into a lens that works over a pair.

Because in the example you don't focus into the first component, you could simply pass `id` as the first lens.

```
sndPerson :: Lens' (a, Person) (a, String)
sndPerson = alongside id name
```

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I was looking for